# Regex with specific criteria issue

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create 2 separate regexes for strings that have these two patterns

STTSHP.COM

- uppercase
- one letter repeats ONLY twice
- no digits
- only ever 6 letters before the .com

YNGFUV.COM

- uppercase
- no letter repeats
- no digits
- only ever 6 letters before the .com

I came up with this regex, but it doesn't seem to be working. What about it is wrong?

```
^(?=(?:[A-Z\D]*[A-Z]{6})(?:([A-Z\D])(?!.*\1)){6}\.COM$
```

Comment: so you don't care about repeats?

Comment: I do in the sense that I do not want any letters to repeat in the first regex. in the second regex I only want  2 letters to repeat. hope that makes sense. let me know if you want any clarification :)

Comment: the second one there would be a valid vaLue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the problem here is a regex that would fulfil all conditions:

```sh
^([A-Z])(?![A-Z]*\1)(?:([A-Z])\2(?!\2)(?:([A-Z])(?![A-Z]*\3)){3}|(?:([A-Z])(?![A-Z]*\4)){5})\.COM$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CYrW3i/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `([A-Z])`: Match an uppercase letter and capture in group #1
- `(?!\1)`: Make sure first letter is not repeated
- `(?:`: Stare non-capture group

  - `([A-Z])\2`: Match an uppercase letter and capture in group #2. Match same letter again using `\2`.
  - `(?!\2)`: Make sure same letter is not repeated again 3rd time
  - `(?:([A-Z])(?!\3)){3}`: Match any 3 letters ensure there are no adjacent repeats
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?:([A-Z])(?!\4)){5}`: Match 5 uppercase letter that don't allow any adjacent repeats
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `\.COM`: Match `.COM`
- `$`: End

Answer (score 1):

You can assert that there are no 3 of the same uppercase chars.

```
^(?![A-Z]*([A-Z])[A-Z]*\1[A-Z]*\1)[A-Z]{6}\.COM$
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what to the right is not

  - `[A-Z]*([A-Z])[A-Z]*\1[A-Z]*\1` Match 3 of the same uppercase chars
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `[A-Z]{6}`
- `\.COM$` Match `.COM` at the end of the string

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y3G4li/1).

Comment: thank you! it doesn't seem to match in my regex 101 for some reason? also, I edited my post. I can tweak this to meet the new criteria.

Comment: ah sorry, there was an extra space in the tester. this works! thank you.